# confusion past tense and present tense,

Tags: tense

if I say

1. I told you to wait until he came back.
2. I told you to wait until he comes back.

which one is correct? if both sounds nothing wrong to you, what's the  difference?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here, one is past tense vs. present tense and the other is [back-shifting reported speech.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm)

> I told you, "Wait until he **comes** back."

If I change this to reported speech, I can backshift the verb tense within the quote to be in the past tense:

> I told you to wait until he **came** back.

Without any context, we can't know the relative time frame of all these events. Has he come back yet or not?

> I told you to wait until he came back.

(Reported speech of something I told you in the past, but it's unclear whether he has come back yet or not)

> I told you to wait until he comes back.

(Reported speech of something I told you in the past, and he hasn't yet come back)

You can use either, because the person you're talking to knows the context -- when they were told, whether "he" has come back, etc.